# How to use HTML entities in links in Drupal 8?

Tags: 8, navigation

I have a client who prefers some links to have the » symbol at the end. This is typically produced with the » HTML character entity.

In Drupal 7, you would do something like this:

```
l('Go there &raquo;', 'node/1', array('html' => TRUE));
```

But how do you do it in Drupal 8? The following won't work because of new sanitization rules:

```
$node->toLink('Go there &raquo;', 'canonical', ['html' => TRUE]);
```

They want the raquo in the link, not as a suffix.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Translate the string

```
$node->toLink(t('Go there &raquo;'))
```

This puts the string in a translatable markup object. If you don't want to translate then use a non translatable markup `\Drupal\Core\Render\Markup::create()`.

Both mark the string as a safe string, which you should do only for string constants like in this case, not for user input.

Comment: That works great, thanks. Quick followup: If I wanted to wrap part of the link text in a span, would it still be correct usage of translatable markup to do the following?
          `$label = new TranslatableMarkup('<span>Next</span> &raquo;');`

Comment: Yes, this is OK, you find similar examples in core.

Answer (score 1):

The cleanst solution for this is doing it in CSS:

```
.my_link_css_class::after {
  content: '\00a0\00bb';
}
```

(`\00a0` is for a space, `\00bb` is for the »)